# How to implement DocumentFilter that inserts URLs as hyperlinks in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, url, jtextpane, documentfilter

I have a `JTable` which uses `JTextPane` as editor and renderer. I added a keyListener to the editor, that listens for "space" character and checks if the last word is URL and if it is, adds it to the editor as a hyperlink using this attribute: `attrs.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF, url);`. I soon figured that this won't convert URLs to hyperlinks when I paste text so I decided I need to do this using `DocumentFilter`.

How can I create a `DocumentFilter` that checks if the  text about to be inserted/replaced contains URLs and if it does inserts/replaces thoose URLs with the `HTML.Attribute.HREF` attribute and the rest of the text as it is?

Answer (score 1):

See the example http://java-sl.com/tip_autocreate_links.html
It's not necessary to use a DocumentFilter. LIstener is enough.

Just mark inserted content with a dummy attribute and then replace it with hyperlink html.

Comment: I already have something similar to this, that listens for " " and "\n", but this won't  work if you paste text, which is why I need documentfilter.

Comment: Implement a one single method to check range of text between 2 offsets. When you paste text DocumentListener is also called (may be multiple times). Pass the offsets from events to the method and process the changed fragment.

Comment: hmmm .. interesting. Though: don't we expect problems when modifying the notifying doc in a DocumentListener? Like in the general rule: never-ever change the state of the caller in a callback method. Always thought that the DocumentFilter is the (only) safe way around those ...

Comment: @kleopatra I agree. That's exactly why I insist on using DocumentFilter. Do you have any reference for a DocumentFilter implementation for this purpose?

Comment: @Igor no, but I would just (didn't try, though) take stani's code and move it to a filter

Comment: @kleopatra just call the code in DocumentListener wrapping with SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Answer (score -1):

```
// somewhere add text reformated as html link
setText("<HTML>Click the <FONT color=\"#000099\"><U>link</U></FONT>"
        + " to go to the Java website.</HTML>");

// somewhere add a listener for clicks
addActionListener(new OpenUrlAction());

// Define uri and open action
 final URI uri = new URI("http://java.sun.com");
    class OpenUrlAction implements ActionListener {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        open(uri);
      }
    }

// Define open uri method
private static void open(URI uri) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
      try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
      } catch (IOException e) { /* TODO: error handling */ }
    } else { /* TODO: error handling */ }
```

Comment: I don't know if I can make my question clearer, but I need to create a `DocumentListener`. The other parts that open links and convert default cursor to hand cursor are already done. Please remove this answer as it doesn't fit my question.

Comment: then why don't you use HTMLEditorKit there also HTMLEditorKit.LinkController class exists.

Comment: That's a mouse listener which listents for mouse clicks on hyperlinks which are already added. I want the app to convert URLs to hyperlinks as you type.